# Why are two maximum power dissipation mentioned for this transistor?

Tags: bjt

I am wondering why manufacturers mention two different maximum power dissipation values for transistors like [2N1613](https://my.centralsemi.com/get_document.php?cmp=1&mergetype=pd&mergepath=pd&pdf_id=2N1613.PDF):

[image: 2N1613 datasheet on the power dissipation]

Does it have anything to do with whether a heatsink is used or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally transistor power dissipation is quoted for T<sub>A</sub> and T<sub>C</sub>. [Renesas](https://en-eu.knowledgebase.renesas.com/?title=English_Content/Analog%26Power/Basic_Information/Power_Devices/What_are_the_difference_between_TA_%3D_25%C2%B0C_and_TC_%3D_25%C2%B0C%3F) explain it as follows:

> The specification at **T<sub>A</sub>** = 25°C in the power ratings refers to the total power dissipation of a discrete semiconductor element in an environment with an **ambient temperature of 25°C**. In this case, the thermal resistance from the heat source to the ambient air is expressed as R<sub>th(j-a)</sub>.
>
> The specification at **T<sub>C</sub>** = 25°C in the power ratings refers to the total power dissipation when the semiconductor element (case) itself has been forcibly cooled, i.e., when **temperature of the package surface is kept at 25°C**.
>
> Note that the ratings may include the note "with infinite heat sink". However, in actual use, it is very difficult to make the package surface temperature exactly 25°C, and if you also take derating into account, the allowable power will in fact be somewhere in between T<sub>A</sub> = 25°C and T<sub>C</sub> = 25°C.

In your example, the maximum power dissipation when T<sub>C</sub> = 25°C is 3.0 W and the maximum power dissipation when T<sub>A</sub> = 25°C is 0.8 W. Note that when the ambient temperature is 25°C the case temperature is likely much higher, so the maximum power rating must be lower.

Adequate cooling makes a big difference.

Answer (score 2):

They're limits for different operating conditions:

[image]

So the first limit is when the case temperature (\$T_C\$) is held at 25 C by some means (for example with a heat sink and forced air cooling, or just by operating the part with low duty cycle).

And the second one is when the ambient temperature (\$T_A\$) is 25 C, so the case will be heating up above that temperature.